# How do I get a return value for BMI in this loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on an assignment to create a code that receives input from the user on a name, weight, and height and then returns a BMI value and then loops back to ask for another name. I cannot seem to get my BMI function to return an output though.

```
def BMI(BMI):
    num1, num2 = weight, height
    BMI = (num1 * 706)/(num2^2)
    return BMI
user = str
end = "x"
while user != end:
    print()
    user = input("Please enter player name or type 'X' to quit: ")
    if user == end:
        print("Report Complete")
        break
    else:
        num1 = (float(input("Please enter weight: ")))
        num2 = (float(input("Please enter height: ")))
    if num1 >= 1:
        print("BMI: "(BMI))
```

i receive this error: "" when I run the function.

I'm looking for an input that is along the lines of

Please enter player name or press 'X' to quit: xxx
Please enter weight: xxx
Please enter height: xxx
BMI: xxx

Please enter player name or press 'X' to quit:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so there are a few things that you'll want to fix for this to work.

- When you are printing, you are not calling the function correctly and python thinks you're trying to use `"BMI: "` as a function. How you want to call `BMI` is like `BMI(weight, height)` where you pass in the values for weight and height as parameters. `BMI` returns a float, so you'll need to turn it into a string before appending it. The result of those changes are `"BMI: "+ str(BMI(num1, num2))`
- In the definition of your `BMI` function, you'll want to pass in the weight and height as parameters like so: `def BMI(weight, height):`. This will allow you to use both `weight` and `height` in the function body.
- The `^` in python does not mean power, it means bitwise xor. You want to use the `**` operator like so: `BMI = (num1 * 706)/(num2**2)`

After making those changes, you should end up with something like this:

```
def BMI(weight, height):
    num1, num2 = weight, height
    BMI = (num1 * 706.0)/(num2**2)
    return BMI
user = str
end = "x"
while user != end:
    print()
    user = input("Please enter player name or type 'X' to quit: ")
    if user == end:
        print("Report Complete")
        break
    else:
        num1 = (float(input("Please enter weight: ")))
        num2 = (float(input("Please enter height: ")))
    if num1 >= 1:
        print("BMI: " + str(BMI(num1, num2)))
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much! That cleared it all up. I really appreciate how helpful your answer was.